# Sens de "On ne souffle pas derrière"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Dans une émission québécoise nommé « Silence, on joue », l'animateur dit toujours aux participant-e-s qu'on ne souffle pas derrière avant qu'il ne pose une question. Quel est le sens de cette phrase?

Voici [un épisode](https://ici.tou.tv/silence-on-joue/S03E03?lectureauto=1) (pour ceux et celles qui habitent au Canada). Vous pouvez trouvez des extraits de cette phrase partout, mais il y a un exemple à 6:58. Ou bien, [cet extrait-là](https://www.dropbox.com/s/me8ohi2lnxpiwrx/Silence%2C%20on%20joue%21.mp4?dl=0), pour ceux et celles qui ne peuvent pas y accéder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Souffler signifie donner discrètement la réponse. Derrière fait référence au public. « On ne souffle pas derrière » veut juste dire que le public ne doit pas donner de réponse discrètement au candidat.

Comment: J'ajoute que cette expression existe aussi en France.

Comment: Souffler vient du théâtre, ou la personne, le souffeur, était dans un espace en dessous de la scène et rappellait aux acteurs leurs textes. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Souffleur_(th%C3%A9%C3%A2tre)

Comment: [TLFi II C. 2.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/souffler) ; ce n'est pas un régionalisme, ni même une expression mais un emploi au figuré du verbe _souffler_ dans le sens de _dans un [souffle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/souffle)_. Merci.